# Not able to bind onchange event to lit-flatpickr element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, web-component, lit-element

```
import 'lit-flatpickr';
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit-element';

class MyApp extends LitElement {
getValue() {
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-date-picker').getValue();
}

getSelectedDate(){
console.log('selected date');
}

render() {
return html<lit-flatpickr id="my-date-picker" altInput altFormat="F j, Y" dateFormat="Y-m-d" theme="material_orange" minDate="2020-01" maxDate="2020-12-31" @change="${this.getSelectedDate}" ></lit-flatpickr>;
}
}
```

`getSelectedDate` is not triggering at all. Can you help us how invoke hooks and methods of lit-flatpickr?

https://github.com/Matsuuu/lit-flatpickr

Comment: Your code doesn't have the **`** (backticks) as shown on the documentation page...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
(async function() {

await import('https://unpkg.com/lit-flatpickr?module');
const { html, css, LitElement } = await import('https://unpkg.com/lit?module');

class MyApp extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      lit-flatpickr {
        background: pink;
      }
    `;
  }
  
  get picker() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-date-picker')
  }
  
  getValue() {
    this.picker.getValue();
  }

  getSelectedDates(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return html `
      <lit-flatpickr id="my-date-picker"
          altInput
          allowInput
          altFormat="F j, Y"
          dateFormat="Y-m-d"
          theme="material_orange"
          minDate="2020-01"
          maxDate="2020-12-31"
          .onChange="${this.getSelectedDates}"
      ></lit-flatpickr>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-app', MyApp);

})();
```

```html
<my-app id="app"></my-app>
```

`<lit-flatpickr>` (at least the version i got as of this writing) doesn't have any DOM events, you have to pass these custom `on*` functions instead.

Comment: Works for me even 3 years ago :)